# General formula for multiplying two degree-two polynomials together?

Tags: polynomials

I am trying to figure out a general formula for getting the product of two degree-2 polynomials.

For example, I have $ax^2+bx+c$ and want to multiply it by $dx^2+ex+f$ where all variables are constants except for $x$. What would be the product of these two polynomials?

I tried computing the general formula, but I don't believe I got the correct answer. 
Thanks for your help!

What I got was $adx^4 + (ae+bd)x^3 + (af+be+cd)x^2 + (ce+bf)x + cf$.

Answer (score 2):

$$(a_{_2}x^2+a_{_1}x+a_{_0})\cdot(b_{_2}x^2+b_{_1}x+b_{_0})=\sum_{k=0}^4\sum a_i\cdot b_{k-i}\cdot x^k$$

Comment: With the added mention that both *i* and $k-i$ have to be in between $0$ and $2$.

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$(ax^2+bx+c)(dx^2+ex+f)=ax^2(dx^2+ex+f)+bx(dx^2+ex+f)+c(dx^2+ex+f).$$
Do the multiplications mentioned on the right. We get 
$$(adx^4+aex^3+afx^2)+(bdx^3+bex^2+bfx)+(cdx^2+cex+cf).$$
Now gather like powers of $x$ together. We get
$$adx^4+(ae+bd)x^3+(af+be+cd)x^2+(bf+ce)x+cf.$$

**Added:** The answer you added is correct.

Comment: Oh okay, so I was correct then. Interesting... Ok. Thank you!
And do you know if this should work for any constants plugged into a, b, c, d, e, or f?

Comment: When I was typing you had not yet written what you got. And you were not off at all, I had a typo.

Comment: Note that the answer by Lucian is better, since it readily generalizes.